# Modify HTTP response on the fly NOT using Fiddler2

Tags: http, networking, code-injection, wireshark

Let`s assume that program 'xyz' use pretty simple authentication via HTTP/1.1 GET method. What i want to do is modify response header, exactly  from "Content: 1; Bad User Name or Password" to "Content: 0; Pass".

To be more specific:

0) I'm using win 7 x86, program 'xyz' was written in VB. Fiddler is not capturing packets, btw don't know why ;-(  => i wanted to use AutoResponder. Wireshark captures nicely ;-)

1) I run 'xyz' and fill credentials: User Name  = 'fake_foo' and Password = 'fake_bar' than press `login`

2) In wireshark i see HTTP request packet to 111.222.223.224:80:

```
    GET /result?u=fake_foo&p=fake_bar HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: CheckL
    TimeStamp: 1234567890
    Host: 111.222.223.224:80
```

3) Next packet is response from that server:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: 05:00:00 AM
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content: 1;Bad User Name or Password
```

Now when i put reliable credentialas than response is:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: 05:00:00 AM
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content: Content: 0; Pass
```

and program starts.

How to, what software can use to modify on the fly this response to be 'pass' after sending request with fake data?

Thanks